# Angular 5 fill empty array with httpget

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable, angular5

I have an empty array(productsWithCategory) and i try to  fill it on click event. But it is not working on first click. When i click once, array does not fill. After first click, everything works. But i really don't know why. Can you help me?

Sorry for my english.

**category.component.html :**

```html
<h4 class="page-header">Categories</h4>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a 
        class="list-group-item" 
        *ngFor="let category of categoryList"
        (click)="getProducts(category.categoryId)">
        {{category.categoryName}}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-lg-9">
    <div class="list-group">
      <a 
        class="list-group-item" 
        *ngFor="let product of productsWithCategory">
        {{product.productName}}
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**category.component.ts:**

```js
import { Component, OnInit, DoCheck } from '@angular/core';
import { CategoryService } from './category.service';
import { Category } from './category';
import { Product } from '../product/product';
import { ProductService } from '../product/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-category',
  templateUrl: './category.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./category.component.css'],
  providers: [CategoryService, ProductService]
})
export class CategoryComponent implements OnInit {
  categoryList: Category[];
  productsWithCategory: Product[] = [];
  constructor(
    private categoryService: CategoryService, 
    private productService: ProductService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.getCategories();
  }

  getCategories() {
    return this.categoryService.getCategories().subscribe(p => this.categoryList = p);
  }

  getProducts(categoryId: number) {
    this.productsWithCategory = this.productService.getProductsByCategory(categoryId);
  }
}
```

**product.service.ts:**

```js
import { Injectable, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { Product } from './product';
import { ProductList } from './product-list.mock';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http'
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/do'
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch'

@Injectable()
export class ProductService {
  constructor(
    private http: Http, 
    @Inject('apiUrl') private apiUrl
  ) {}

  productsByCategory: Product[] = [];
  getProducts(): Observable < Product[] > {
    return this.http.get(this.apiUrl + "products").map(response => response.json());
  }

  getProductsByCategory(categoryId: number) {
    this.getProducts().subscribe(x => this.productsByCategory = x.filter((s: Product) => s.categoryId == categoryId, x));

    **
    * //this.productsByCategory => is empty on first click***
    return this.productsByCategory;
  }
}
```

Comment: Because your `return` is called before `subscribe` when the code executes

Comment: A simple fix is to wait for categoryList and productsWithCategory with a `ngIf(categoryList)`

Comment: @David what do you mean? Because subsribe is async?

Answer (score 1):

`this.getProducts()` is an asynchronous operation. So if you just return `this.productsByCategory` after calling that function, the call won't have finished. After that, of course, if you call the function, the asynchronous operation will have (probably) finished, and you'll receive the last data you retrieved. In fact, you could retrieve wrong results, as you always get the products filtered by the last call that finished, disregarding the actual `categoryId` you pass as parameter.

In fact, if you make several calls and they stop working (because you lose connection to the server) you keep 'receiving' data, though that data doesn't change.

You should return an Observable from getProductsByCategory:

```
return this.getProducts().filter(s => s.categoryId === categoryId);
```

Then you could subscribe to the observable in the calling function or use the `async` pipe in the template.

Comment: thank you for explanation.when i use "this.getProducts().filter(s => s.categoryId === categoryId);", i get error like this: property filter does not exist on type observable<Product[]>

Comment: You must import the `filter` operator, like you import `map` or `do`.